# IntelliJ grouped .form and .class under a directory, is that the same as having them ungrouped?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have some package where [originally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auZej.jpg) there was a folder like structure that housed both the .java class and the .form.

I copied the package over but it became [ungrouped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY5Ke.jpg) and now there is no 'parent folder' thing, instead the .class and .form both just sit in the same package together. Are these two equivalent?

I inspected both packages in the file explorer, and the contents are identical, only those two files are there in the file explorder so I'm wondering if this is just some IntelliJ formatting behavior?

Comment: Does the code still work, do you have `bind to class` property set correctly for the form?

Comment: @CrazyCoder ah that did the trick! Code seems to work either way, but I changed the property. If the code works without proper binding, what is the purpose of binding? Forgive my ignorance, never used .forms before

Comment: It should not work without binding.

Comment: I see, well I guess the code just never called that section when I was running. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Bind to class property in the form must be set correctly.